# jQuery load() method parameters usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to jQuery load() method api:

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

1. 1st parameter is url
2. 2nd parameter is map or string that is sent to the server
3. 3rd parameter is callback function.

With the working example below

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

it supplies arguments of 'url' and 'callback function', [data] argument is skipped.

**Shouldn't the example code treat the callback function as [data] argument (2nd parameter) ? Because of the order that parameters defined in the API . By following the API, 1st is url, 2nd is data, 3rd is callback.**

I don't get why the code would work. Very confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very clearly written in the jQuery source code.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js

Search for `load: function( url, params, callback )`

It checks for the params (second parameter) and if it exist, It will call the `isFunction` method which internally check the type of the argument and return true if it is a function.  The rest you know....

[image]

This is how `isFunction` looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, It inspects the datatype of the parameters. If it finds a function as the second parameter then it uses it as a callback.

The position and order of the parameters has been thought out with the typical use-cases in mind and in stead of having to give a null value to skip a parameter .load('url', null, null, function() {}); you just imagine that the parameters "shift" places when skipped.

This applies to a lot of functions not just .load.

Comment: thx, the datatype inspection is jQuery's feature ro javascript's feature?  With other language such as PHP, we always need to follow the order.

Comment: Not true, you can do the same in PHP too, an it's a JS feature not a jquery feature.

Comment: The same type inspection can be used in PHP to obtain similar results. When you define the method you don't name the parameters in the function header, and you fetch all supplied parameters from **func_get_args()** you inspect their types and decide what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets (`[]`) around a parameter in the documentation indicate that it is optional. So your example is perfectly valid according to said documentation.

Comment: I understand it is optional. But shouldn't the extra augments follow the parameter order defined?

Comment: They do. Since `data` is optional, it is perfectly valid to supply a callback function as the second argument.

Comment: then why load() won't treat "function() {alert('Load was performed.'); })"  as [data] argument, as its position is in 2nd

Comment: Andrew, in most other programming languages the **convention** for skipping optional arguments is to use the default value of that parameter or if it's the last parameter to not include it at all. The jQuery convention is helpful but I can understand why this would be considered unintuitive at first.

Comment: He knows that it is valid to ignore it but he is not sure how jquery understands whether 2nd argument is for params or callback

Comment: The question led me to believe the OP was confused by the documentation (especially the bolded bit in the question). Under the hood, jQuery is looking at each argument to determine which one of the optional parameters you are specifying.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: I'm not sure I agree with that. Plenty of languages allow method overloading which allows for the appearance of methods that take different combinations of optional parameters.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker What do you disagree with: Other languages have a convention of using the default value or null for skipping optional arguments? Or: the convention jQuery uses is helpful and might be intuitive to a rookie but if you've seen the other convention a lot it'll be unituitive at first.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: The first bit. Take a language like C#. Most of the types in `System` do not make you supply a default value for an optional parameter, they simply supply an overload that omits that parameter.

Comment: In strong-typed languages it's less optimal to create overloads with different parameters for every possible use-case, because the API becomes larger and harder to maintain (after changing the underlying function for example). Scripting languages like PHP & JavaScript have no overloads but give you access to all passed arguments (even those exceeding the parameters named in the header of the function). I'm curious, do other libraries/frameworks offer the same overloads for every possible combination of parameters? It makes sense for **System** because it is highly used.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout jquery's source file ajax.js in Github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L178

Here it checks whether second argument is function. If yes, it takes it as the callback and params as `undefined`.

Comment: thanks. great find, is the checking of argument datatype also applying to other jQuery method?

Comment: Once it determines which is params and which is callback, it calls jQuery.ajax method to provide parameters correctly. As you know, `.load` is just a shorthand method for `jQuery.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in the specification means that the parameters are optional, so you can use any of these forms:

```
.load(url, data, complete)
.load(url, data)
.load(url, complete)
.load(url)
```

The method will figure out if the second parameter is a callback function or a data object/string depending on the data type.